# Ripple color submenu item in toolbar

Tags: android, menu, ripple

I am using xml to create menus and submenus on my toolbar.

They are using black with alpha ripple color.

Meanwhile in other menu I am using popup menu and it is using colorControlHighlight (gold color added in my style).

Is there a way to add this gold color to the ripples generated in a submenu created via xml?

Answer (score 2):

Well I solved it using colorControlHighlight directly in my toolbar.

Styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

layout_with_my_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:title="Toolbar Title"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStyle">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```